# Elegant way to run parallel threads in Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, nonblocking, countdownlatch

I am developing an API. This API needs to do 2 DB queries to get the result.

I tried following strategies:

- Used callable as return type in Controller.
- Created 2 threads in Service (use Callable and CoundownLatch) to run 2 queries parallel and detect finishing time.

  ```
  public class PetService {
      public Object getData() {
          CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);
          AsyncQueryDBTask<Integer> firstQuery= new AsyncQueryDBTask<>(latch);
          AsyncQueryDBTask<Integer> secondQuery= new AsyncQueryDBTask<>(latch);
          latch.await();
  }

  public class AsyncQueryDBTask<T> implements Callable {

     private CountDownLatch latch;

     public AsyncQueryDBTask(CountDownLatch latch) { this.latch = latch;}

     @Override
     public T call() throws Exception {
      //Run query
      latch.countDown();
     }
  ```

It worked fine but I feel that I am breaking the structure of Spring somewhere.

I wonder what is the most efficient way to get data in Spring 4.

-How to know both of 2 threads that run own query completed their job?

-How to control thread resource such as use and release thread?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-and-java-thread-example/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You generally don't want to create your own threads in an ApplicationServer nor manage thread lifecycles.  In application servers, you can submit tasks to an `ExecutorService` to pool background worker threads.

Conveniently, Spring has the `@Async` annotation that handles all of that for you.  In your example, you would create 2 async methods that return a Future :

```
public class PetService {
    public Object getData() {
        Future<Integer> futureFirstResult = runFirstQuery();
        Future<Integer> futureSecondResult = runSecondQuery();

        Integer firstResult = futureFirstResult.get();
        Integer secondResult = futureSecondResult.get();
    }

    @Async
    public Future<Integer> runFirstQuery() {
        //do query
        return new AsyncResult<>(result);
    }

    @Async
    public Future<Integer> runSecondQuery() {
        //do query
        return new AsyncResult<>(result);
    }
}
```

As long as you configure a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and enable async methods, Spring will handle submitting the tasks for you.

NOTE: The `get()` method blocks the current thread until a result is returned by the worker thread but doesn't block other worker threads.  It's generally advisable to put a timeout to prevent blocking forever.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is really helpful.
Please help me one more question. Is it ok to do it:

```java
List l = new ArrayList();
l.add(future1.get());
l.add(future2.get());
```

Comment: Yes that's fine.  The get call returns the value in the future always (or throws an exception if you use the timeout version)

Comment: I guess in your example it will not work, because you call async method from class directly, self-invocation doesn't work because it bypasses the proxy and calls the underlying method directly.